# GIT - ssh Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

I am unable to perform any operations on GIT bash (pull, push, clone etc.) - getting below error:

*$ git clone ssh://git@stash.gto.intranet.com:7999/~shashank.khanduja@test.com/hello-java.git
Cloning into 'hello-java'...
git@stash.gto.intranet.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.*

I have tried deleting all the files from .ssh folder and recreated the keys. But, still the same issue.

Also, refer below error:
*ssh -T git@stash.gto.intranet.com:7999
ssh: Could not resolve hostname stash.gto.intranet.com:7999: Name or service not known*

Comment: Your "ssh -T" command is failing because you added the port number to the end of the hostname. Try running "ssh -p 7999 -T git@stash.gto.intranet.com", then [edit] your question to show the command that you ran and the result that you got.

Comment: @Kenster - getting below error:

ssh -p 7999 -T git@stash.gto.intranet.com
git@stash.gto.intranet.com: Permission denied (publickey).